# Pandas - How it is possible to generate trees out of 2 column file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, directed-acyclic-graphs

My data file looks like the following:

```
1 2
3 4
4 5
5 7
1 8
8 20
```

Note that the data consists of "edges" of directed acyclic graph, left to right (e.g. (4,5) is a directed edge in the graph).

What I want, by using only Pandas tools is to receive the following file:

```
1 2
3 4 5 7
1 8 20
```

Which represents the full graph or the "forest" of the data.
Note - There is no bound for the number of children.

Comment: Are you sure it is good to use eaxctly CSV format for this? Why dont use dot format for graphs?

Comment: How many children may each node have?

Comment: @paveltr Actually it doesn't. I will edit the post

Comment: @piripiri There is no bound for the number of children

Comment: Where does the `5 6` line come from in your example output?

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko It should't. I fixed, thanks